# qmake on a mac missing for qt-creator

Tags: c++, qt4, qt-creator, qmake

I am working on Mac OS X at the moment, and wanted to start building apps using **Qt Creator**. 
Unfortunately i can't build any applications as it gives me an error saying that *qmake's path is not found or qmake is missing*.

I tried using netbeans, which works perfectly with simple c/c++ programs, but for qt apps it then gives me the same error.
My version of Xcode 4 works perfectly and builds without any problems.

Any ideas?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not enough to just download the `Qt Creator`, you need to download the complete sdk: http://qt.nokia.com/downloads (almost 1GiB)

Comment: Well, I downloaded and compiled the qt4-mac toolkit via MacPorts (which took several hours to build), so i thought it was the same thing. Thanks though, i will try this way i guess..

Comment: if you installed qt4-mac through MacPorts, you probably don't have to install the sdk from the nokia-website. Try installing qt4-mac-devel and look in /opt/local/bin for the `qmake`

Comment: well qmake was indeed in the /opt/local/bin but even when i manually changed the path in qt-creator, it still wouldnt work. Anyways, the qt sdk fixed my solution :)

Comment: With port `qt4-mac` manually liking `qmake` is now needed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31315354/qt5-and-macports-missing-links

Answer (score 1):

My Macbook is no longer my primary computer. But, when it was, I found out through painful experiences that it was best to install software from MacPorts whenever what you wanted was available from http://www.macports.org/

Even more important, I also discovered that when software was not offered from MacPorts, it was invariably because that particular software did not install without some sort of tweaking on a Mac. Hence, since Macports does not currently offer Qt v5, and I had problems installing the qt-project.com Qt v5.2.1 SDK on my Macbook, I would advise to go with the MacPort for Qt v4.8.5 [qt4-mac] which includes qmake. Qt Creator is available as a separate MacPort [qt4-creator-mac].

Here is how I successfully installed Qt v4.8.5 [with qmake] and Qt Creator on my Macbook:

1) 'sudo port install qt4-mac'

2) 'sudo port install qt4-creator-mac'

3) I used Finder to run Qt Creator which was in the /Applications/MacPorts/Qt4 folder.

4) When I first ran Qt Creator, its Preferences dialog listed the auto-installed Desktop kit, but that kit had no Qt version, no qmake, and no debugger.

5) Manually added a second kit.

6) Configured kit's Qt version for /opt/local/bin/qmake, which is where qt4-mac installed qmake. This was enough for the kit to now discover Qt v4.8.5 which had been installed by qt4-mac.

7) Used kit's auto-detect feature to now discover the debugger.

8) Configured that kit to be the default kit.