# Qt5 and MacPorts: missing links

Tags: macos, qt, macports

I'm wondering if somebody has also a similar "problem" while installing Qt5 from MacPorts.

I've installed a frech MacPorts distribution yesterday (on Yosemite) and installed the ports `qt5-mac` and `qt5-creator-mac`. First, I have noticed that (compared with my previous experience) there is no longer a link to Qt Creator in the `/Applications/MacPorts` folder. In addition, the tools like `qmake` are no longer in the path (that is, there are no links to files from `/opt/local/libexec/qt5-mac/bin` in `/opt/local/bin`). Of course, it is not a serious problem; I'm just wondering if this is the indended behavior or a possible bug.

Comment: I had the same issue yesterday, when I installed `qt4-mac @4.8.7_2` with MacPorts 2.3.4 on OS X 10.8.5.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is intended behavior. It's a first step to allowing multiple Qt versions to coexist.

If you wish to use a particular Qt version from the command line, you need to add its binary path to your path.

Comment: For QT5 I just did `find /opt/ -name qmake` to get the path and then `ln -s /opt/local/libexec/qt5/bin/qmake /opt/local/bin/qmake`